# java wild card List<?> is reifiable but not List<Object>

Tags: java, generics

How `List<?>` and `List<Object>` is not reifiable what is the exact reason for this. I didn't understand the intent behind that. As the java generics is implemented by type erasure but not by dynamic casts etc.. while compilation, what is the reasoning behind the that, It seems to be confusing to me to grasp the exact concept, what compiler will do exactly inside while generating the byte code.

Comment: Your title is "why wild card list is reifiable" and your first sentence is "How List<?> ... is not reifiable"; please clarify what you're asking.

Comment: this is well explained in bloch's effective java: http://www.eecs.qmul.ac.uk/~mmh/APD/bloch/generics.pdf

Comment: Thanks Abhinav and zavior for the answer.

Comment: something whose information is not available at runtime.

Comment: @AbhinavKumar I saw your link and got detailed answer :)